How to solve a producer and consumer problem for very fast UDP data? If I can't limit the producer's work
**Hello, please help me solve the multithreading problem.
Briefly about the problem! Packets of 8190 bytes arrive via udp very quickly, one producer thread puts them in the list and another consumer thread takes them from the list and processes them, but some time is needed for processing, but even in this small time, the producer thread very quickly puts packets in the list and in htop, if you look at memory, they reach 100%.
**
I have a UDPChannelListener class, which is designed to receive data via UDP only. That class has 2 threads void UDPChannelListener::readThread() and void UDPChannelListener::pushThread().
The first is designed to receive a packet via UDP and place the shared_ptr of that packet in a list. The second thread is designed to move packets from that list to another list in sequential order, packets may appear in the first list in the wrong order. I also have a ChannelInterface class, whose pointer is in the UDPChannelListener class. In that class there is a thread that should take the packets from the already sorted list and send them to the client via tcp.
Now it is done so that when receiving some sorted part ChannelInterface::sendDataThread sends this data and ChannelInterface::PushData waits for the sending to the client to finish. And at the same time the first list still grows very quickly. That is, the consumer thread needs some time to process these packets and while the packets are being processed the list grows and if you look in htop memory reaches 100% and the computer starts to lag with such an implementation of the code. What can you advise on the code what to do if it takes time to process the data and the data goes very quickly and the buffer fills up very quickly. Thank you very much in advance
void UDPChannelListener::readThread()
{
_receivedPacketCount.store(0);
while (_readThreadIsEnabled.load())
{
    // return shared_ptr of a udp packet
    auto packet = receiveUDPPacket();
    if (packet)
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(_lstMutex);
            _udpPackets.push_back(packet);
        }
        _cv_Packets.notify_one();
    }
    else
    {
        size_t packetsSize = 0;
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(_lstMutex);
            packetsSize = _udpPackets.size();
        }
        if (packetsSize)
        {
            _cv_Packets.notify_one();

            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(_lstMutex);
                _cv_Packets.wait(locker, [&] {
                    return packetsSize > _udpPackets.size() || !_readThreadIsEnabled.load();
                });
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1));
        }
    }
}


void UDPChannelListener::pushThread()
{
std::shared_ptr<Common::udpIQData> packet;

while (_readThreadIsEnabled.load())
{
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(_lstMutex);
        _cv_Packets.wait(locker, [&] {
            return !_udpPackets.empty() || !_readThreadIsEnabled.load();
        });

        if (!_readThreadIsEnabled.load())
        {
            return;
        }
        packet = _udpPackets.front();
        _udpPackets.pop_front();
    }

    if (packet)
    {
        _monitorReceivedPacketCount.fetch_add(1);
        _receivedPacketCount.fetch_add(1);

        if (auto channelPtr = _channel.lock())
        {
            if (int err = channelPtr->PushData(packet))
            {
                stopReadingThread();
                std::cout << "Error to push data, err: " << err << std::endl;
                std::cout << "Broken data:, remaining: " << _expectedPackets - _receivedPacketCount.load()
                          << std::endl;

                _isDataBroken.store(true);
                _readThreadIsEnabled.store(false);
            }
        }
    }
    _cv_Packets.notify_one();
}
}
int ChannelInterface::PushData(std::shared_ptr<Common::udpIQData> recourseHandler)
{
 if (!_isConnected.load())
 {
    return ERROR_DISCONNECTED;
 }
 if (!recourseHandler)
 {
    return ERROR_BAD_PARAMETER;
 }
 auto packetNumber = recourseHandler->header.packet_number;

 if (_packetsToBeProcessed[packetNumber])
 {
    return ERROR_BROKEN_DATA;
 }
 _packetsToBeProcessed[packetNumber] = recourseHandler;

 uint8_t prevExpected = _expectedPacketNumber;
 {
     std::lock_guard<std::mutex> locker(_udpPacketsLstMtx);
     while (_packetsToBeProcessed[_expectedPacketNumber])
     {
         if (int err = _dataFlowManager- >addPacket(_packetsToBeProcessed[_expectedPacketNumber]))
         {
            return err;
         }
         _packetsToBeProcessed[_expectedPacketNumber].reset();
         ++_expectedPacketNumber;
     }
 }
 if (prevExpected != _expectedPacketNumber)
 {
     _cv_udpPacketsLstReady.notify_one();

     std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(_udpPacketsLstMtx);
     _cv_udpPacketsLstReady.wait(locker, [&] {
        return _dataFlowManager->lstIsEmpty() || !_isConnected.load();
     });

     if (!_isConnected.load())
     {
         return ERROR_DISCONNECTED;
     }
 }
 return ERROR_NO_ERROR;
}

void ChannelInterface::sendDataThread()
{
 std::list<std::shared_ptr<Common::udpIQData>> packets;
 while (_sendingThreadIsEnabled.load())
 {
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(_udpPacketsLstMtx);
        _cv_udpPacketsLstReady.wait(locker, [&] {
            return !_dataFlowManager->lstIsEmpty() || !_isConnected.load();
        });

        if (!_isConnected.load())
        {
            _sendingThreadIsEnabled.store(false);
            _cv_udpPacketsLstReady.notify_one();

            return;
        }
        packets = _dataFlowManager->packetLst();
        _dataFlowManager->clearPacketsLst();
    }
    _cv_udpPacketsLstReady.notify_one();

        for (const auto &packet : packets)
        {
            Common::tcpIQData header;
            header.samplesCount = packet->header.packet_length;
            header.t0 = _dataFlowManager->timeStamp();
            uint64_t bytesToSend = sizeof(std::complex<int16_t>) * packet->header.packet_length;

            if (auto client = _client.lock())
            {
                if (int err = client->SendRaw(_desc, header, reinterpret_cast<char *>(&packet->data[0]),
                                              bytesToSend))
                {
                    _sendingThreadIsEnabled.store(false);
                    _dataFlowManager->reset();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}

Have you profiled your code to identify any bottleneck(s)?  Also, from initial reading of the post it sounds like you only have a single consumer thread; why?

Also: https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter5/#Slow-Subscriber-Detection-Suicidal-Snail-Pattern

Thanks @pptaszni for the answer. But I can't block the producer's work because if I do that, UDP packets are lost. I tried to increase the socket buffer size, but it didn't help, the data comes so fast that the buffer immediately becomes full.

Functions like "sleep" only honor the "minimum"; the actual duration is a question.

you are using UDP to afford to throw away packets, otherwise you should be using TCP

If you cannot slow down the producer, and you cannot speed-up the consumer (maybe you can try some parallel processing?), and you cannot drop packets, then uhh then I guess that't it ... your buffer will always get full at some point; It's a classic problem and these are the known solutions, if you come up with something better, you should at least get a PhD for that contribution.

Yes, I tested whether the expected packets would reach the computer at such a speed. The test consisted in the fact that when I received the packet, I simply threw it away and did not perform any actions with it. That is, the error is in the efficiency of packet processing. The loss of packets will lead to the uselessness of the remaining data, since the data is a radio signal, not game data. Thank you for your answer @AhmedAEK.

You can use boost:aasio and do somthing like double buffering. E.g you have one buffer you read data to (and you know you will not be reading from it... so no locks needed). Once that buffer is full, you tell boost to read to another buffer. And then you can process the first buffer. Rince and repeat. In the end it is a tradeoff between responsiveness and throughput.  But at least that way you will not be locking for each single received packet

I like your joke about PhD :) But anyway I think there is something wrong with the code or it can be optimized somehow, this is the first time I have encountered this problem. If I find a solution I will write here and immediately go for my PhD. Thank you for your answer @pptaszni

Re. "the data is a radio signal": can I ask what the encoding/data-rate is?  Seems odd that a radio signal would generate that much data.

Data comes from a board with data rate 250 M/sec @G.M.

Thank you for your answer
@PepijnKramer. I will research it

I don't have the details anymore of what I did, but I ended up receiving 9.98Gb/sec (saturated an optical link) and storing it to a raid array at that speed. I just didn't do any realtime processing but still ;)

@PepijnKramer Well, what can I say, it’s difficult to receive and process so much data in parallel:)

But oh so much fun when you figure it out :)

I think the sleep_for is not needed and can only serve to slow things down because I assume receiveUDPPacket is blocking. Way too much mutex/locking. Way too many shared_ptr

@CraigEstey Thank you for your answer. I researched and realized that lock-free containers like boost::lockfree::spsc_queue will work slower than containers with mutexes
